# How to create a calendar event that repeats weekly for three months every year?

Tags: calendar, icalendar, webcal

I want to be reminded about something every week every winter. Is that possible to achieve using the ical-/webcal-standard and Google Calender, Apple Calendar/iCal, Android Calender or similar?

(I searched quite extensively for which subdomain this questioned belonged to but the results were inconclusive, with a slight predominance for SO)

Comment: Is your question about how to do that in the UI on one of these platforms or is it about how to write an iCalendar RRULE that will accomplish this?

Comment: It is about how to create such an event in any UI available

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible with [RFC 5545 recurrence rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10).

You can create a `WEEKLY` `RRULE` that recurs in specific months only, like so:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO;BYMONTH=1,2,12
```

The occurrences of this rule are all Mondays in January, February and December.

Check out the first 100 instances of such an event at http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20160104&rrule=FREQ%3DWEEKLY%3BBYDAY%3DMO%3BBYMONTH%3D1%2C2%2C12&skip=&max_instances=100&expansion_window_end=21000104&rfc2445=1

Changing the rule to `DAILY` would yield the same results, but might be more compatible with actual implementations.

However, I think most calendar UIs don't provide this level of control over recurrence rules.

#### update:

To create an all day event starting on Dec 15 2015 and recur on the same day of week use:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20151215
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYMONTH=1,2,12
```

The rule doesn't include March itself. To include March just append `,3` to the rule.

Comment: Thank you. Almost there. What remains are (I hope), 1. the event should be all day, 2. I want them to start Dec 15 and reappear every 7 days after that until March. How do I write such a rule?

Comment: can anyone tell me if  there's a way to prevent creating events on the startdate if the startdate does not  fall into the bydate rule? my code `{
            'summary': 'testing the calendar api',
            'start': {'dateTime': '2020-06-04T23:00:00', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Dhaka'},
            'end': {'dateTime': '2020-06-04T23:30:00', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Dhaka'},
            'attendees': [{
                'email': 'ksrahman@iub.edu.bd'
            }],
            'recurrence': ['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR,SA;UNTIL=20200615']
        }`

Comment: @sakib11 you should open another question for this. It's unrelated to the original question.